# Is this PHP Login secure? [Boilerplate]

Tags: php, security, templates, authentication, boilerplate

I have created this php-Login, which will serve as a template.

https://github.com/sinky/php-login-boilerplate

My question, is this php-Login secure? Does it work proper?
Is it possible to get logged in without the password?
(SSL is not taken into consideration.)

Thank you for improvements.
Greetings Marco

Comment: You'll want to post this on http://stackexchange.com/

Comment: This example seems secure enough but the real security vulnerabilities come to play with a database.

Comment: Go through some sample secure php login scripts that are available. Look into how your script could thwart common security attacks - SQL injection, network eavesdropping, brute force. Use `sha1`rather than `md5` (although this is just a suggestion)

Comment: You're having PHP sleep for up to 10 seconds? Not sure how I feel about that. I could just delete the cookie set by your site after every failed attempt and never have to wait X seconds.

Comment: You never have to wait 10 seconds at all, you can just send multiple requests at once. The 'tarpit' only slows down the server, it has no effect on the attacker.

Comment: Also, the `echo` of SCRIPT_NAME should be `htmlspecialchars`ed, as any variable output into HTML. Although this is probably not exploitable, depending on how the web server paths are mapped to the PHP script.

Comment: @bobince: added htmlspecialchars, i now know the tarpit works only against manual attacks over the form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.. not really.

This is vulnerable to CSRF:

```
if($_GET['logout']) {
  session_destroy();    
}
```

This is trivial to bypass,  just clear you cookies each time you attempt to login:

```
sleep($_SESSION['loginFail']);
```

This is good behavior:

```
header("location: login.php");
exit;
```

Keep in mind header() doesn't stop the script from executing.  Also yes,  both the login and the session id must always be transmitted over HTTPS (read: [OWASP A9](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Top_10_2010-A9-Insufficient_Transport_Layer_Protection)).

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I have updated the script to prevent CSRF on logout. I know the tarpit isn't very good, also with regard to the open connection to the Apache.